# doesn't understand this error log

Tags: eclipse

somebody help me fix all this error on log?, thanks in advance
**strong text**
here is the error log of the eclipse IDE I was using.

*http://justpaste.it/1y13*

Answer (score 0):

You ran out of PermGen space. Change your eclipse.ini file to increase the amount of PermGen space.

Comment: I already did. I was just amaze how it get that larger. how could i know my permgen free space and is it possible to flush the memory?